# Back-up camera not working

Tags: backup-camera

https://youtu.be/i47uFC0-ZW8
My Dodge Journey has a back up camera that has suddenly started to intermittently not work. I was going to take it to someone to have them look at it, but every time I make the appointment, it starts to work again. It is getting very frustrating.
Please help. Is it a wiring problem? Would this be covered under my warranty? The car only has 34,500 miles. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Isn't that covered under warranty? Just tell them to fix it as an intermittent problem, whether it is working or not at the time of the appointment. You can show them the video of what is going on.

Comment: My wife's new Accord had a similar issue (1 minute delay rather than failure), and they just replaced several of the components under warranty. With new vehicles (and of course depending on local and laws and warranty agreement) it is usually pretty simple to get them to handle it. Just do it soon before your warranty could lapse.